# Ruby-on-Rails adding current_page? to my link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, current-page

I'd like to add a

```
current_page?
```

to my

```
.navbar.navbar-default.admin-header
  %ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-left
   %li= link_to "Dashboard", admins_dashboard_path, class: 'active'
```

to achieve that if my current page is /dashboard only in that case will be the

```
class: 'active'
```

in my link (later i want to use specific stylesheet to active and not active nav links.

Please helap me to get this together! Thy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/current_page%3F) of this method describes how to implement it. In your case it's going to be something like:

```
.navbar.navbar-default.admin-header
  %ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-left
   %li= link_to "Dashboard", admins_dashboard_path, class: ('active' if current_page?(admins_dashboard_path))
```

Comment: thankyou! i was laerning in typescript and just got involved in a ruby group and everything is so strange atm. this one working perfectly :D